# MongoDb: Failed fetching when _id is both ObjectId and string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So, I have done a migration some time ago and objects were created like this

```
{
   _id: ObjectId('some id value')
}
```

and after a while I have inserted some documents like this

```
{
   _id:'some id value'
}
```

So, when I try to fetch like this: `Document.findById('some id value')`

Nothing is returned. What should I do?

Comment: What were the documents saved in your database as? Can you check using just a general `find`? It seems possible to me that they were inserted and automatically converted to objectids that may not match your original strings.

Comment: They were created with an _id of type ObjectId when I did not specify the _id field and it was created automatically by mongo. 
They were created with an _id of type string when I did specify it. And now the _id field is both of type ObjectId and of type string. I think that's why the fetch fails but I don't know how to fix it